# How to run a multiple .spec.ts file in an angular-cli project?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-jasmine, karma-mocha

I have the multiple spec.ts file path like this `"src/app/app-routing/app-routing.module.spec.ts" "src/app/modules/dashboard/components/bill/gst-bill.component.html"`

I want to run the test case for this spec.ts files, only using angular-cli in a single command. Is this possible?

Comment: I want to execute only using angular-cli only. 
Because, I need to use this in circle-ci parallelism
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/parallelism-faster-jobs/

Answer (score 0):

Instead changine the path with test.ts file we can add the "**f**" before describe block with the spec.ts files that alone you want to run as **fdescribe** and then try to run,

```
ng test
```

only specs with particular spec.ts file will run